# Android SmsManager Don't send sms to the specific number

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I am trying to make an android application which will send an sms when the device first boot up and after sending the sms successfully the application will be destroyed automatically.If the application fails to send the sms then it will try within 30 minutes from the device boot up time again.

But for the test purpose I am trying to send the sms to specific number.but it don't send the sms from the device. here is manifest.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.farhadrakib.waltonmobile.wst"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.NONE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the broadcastReceiver code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver{


    private static final String  DestinationAddress = "+8801746433855";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String DeviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Log.d("DEVICEID",DeviceId);
        //String Line1Number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
        if (DeviceId != null){

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(DestinationAddress, null, "My id: "+DeviceId, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help??I really need some good sugesstion

Comment: What does your logcat show?

Comment: Did you check if deviceId is populated..

Comment: Also post the code in BootReceiverMessageSender class

Comment: I want to debug it through logcat.but it shows nothing.I don't know actually where the error is.but in IDE it shows no error.

Comment: updated the code.Is there any thing I am doing wrong??

Comment: I think you might be confusing Activities and BroadcastReceivers. You have a Receiver class, `BootReceiverMessageSender`, statically registered in the manifest, but it doesn't seem to exist, as your `MainActivity` is what is subclassing the `BroadcastReceiver` class. I think you want your `MainActivity` to `extends Activity`, and you want a separate class `BootReceiverMessageSender` that `extends BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Actually I don't need any activity for this app, it always will run in the  background until it sends the message to a specific number.I have no idea how to do it.Can anyone help with sample code.It's really urgent...@Mike.M

Comment: Well, you'll need an Activity that a user can run at least once after installation to bring the app out of the _stopped_ state (as of version 3.1). I would suggest making `MainActivity` an `Activity` subclass, and creating the `BootReceiverMessageSender extends BroadcastReceiver` class to handle the boot broadcast.

Comment: Is there any way by which user don't have to run the apps.It will run automatically after booting like system application.To be honest this app will be used to track the sales record of our cell phone,it will send a sms with the device id,user phone number and other device info to our sms server from where we can know that how many cell phone we have sold.So how can I make it??Any suggestion?And also I am new to android application development.So please help...@Mike.M